# How to hide Article Fields which are displaying on the front end

Tags: entities

Please help me, i just started learning drupal and implementing it.

I have a problem in hiding fields which are displaying in article pages.

Please check this [page](http://seleniumeasy.com/itext-tutorials/itext-example-to-create-pdf-with-metatags) . "Body" field is displaying in all Articles. Please help me.

Please find the attached screen shot for reference.

> [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Guessing there is no views implemented.

Go to manage display settings of article content type [ `admin/structure/types/manage/article/display` ]. In Label column select 'hidden' for body row.

You are done.